Why does a Rust iterator with a mutable reference fail to compile, while one with an immutable reference works?
I have implemented an iterator that holds a mutable reference, but it fails to compile. Here is the code:
pub struct TokenReader {
    tokens: Vec<i32>,
    pos: usize,
}

pub struct Iter<'a> {
    inner: &'a mut TokenReader,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Iter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.inner.pos < self.inner.tokens.len() {
            let item = &self.inner.tokens[self.inner.pos];
            self.inner.pos += 1;
            Some(item)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}


The above code produces the following compilation error:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:13
   |
10 | impl<'a> Iterator for Iter<'a>{
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
13 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
17 |             Some(item)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`

I tried changing the iterator to hold an immutable reference to TokenReader. Here is the modified code:
pub struct Iter2<'a> {
    inner: &'a TokenReader,
    pos: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Iter2<'a> {
    type Item = &'a i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.pos < self.inner.tokens.len() {
            let item = &self.inner.tokens[self.pos];
            self.pos += 1;
            Some(item)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}


The modified code compiles successfully. Both iterators are supposed to do similar things, with Iter holding a mutable reference and Iter2 holding an immutable reference.
Why does Iter fail to compile while Iter2 succeeds? What is the difference in how Rust handles lifetimes for mutable and immutable references in this context?

Note that this is basically a reimplementation of slice::IterMut

Because shared references implement Copy, self.inner in Iter2 can be copied and thus references to it are independent of self and it's lifetime '1, but exclusive references don't implement Copy so the corresponding self.inner in Iter must be a reborrow of self and hence shortens any lifetime you can give out to '1. Since your signature requires an item with lifetime 'a which is potentially longer you get a lifetime mismatch.

'a is not only potentially longer, it's guaranteed to be longer, since '1 is local to next(), while 'a must outlive the Iter struct instance.

@SvenMarnach the compiler might choose to pick 'a = '1 as both are passed in from outside, we only know '1: 'a because self contains a &'a but that also includes the equal case.

I don't think that's possible. A borrow of a struct containing a reference can't have the same lifetime as the contained reference. The borrow must end before the struct is dropped, while the contained reference must live until after that. (It also doesn't matter that much. I'm just nit picking.)

You most definitely can construct a &'a mut Foo<'a> even if the inner bit has to outlive the struct.

Remember, a lifetime doesn't describe actual, maximal validity ranges of values but rather a minimal part thereof that the referred value (memory location) must be valid for. @SvenMarnach
